Three phase voltage measurement with floating gnd
I am designing a digital circuit based on STM32H743G. There is a 600V AC motor in the application and 3 parallel lines from the 3 phases are entering to the PCB. I have to find a way to measure the voltage levels in the three lines. There are several problems.
The first thing is there is no neutral line. So there is no reference that i can measure the three phases with respect to it. After a bit of research I understand that i have to measure the three phases with respect to each other which is called "rail to rail" if I am not wrong. Practically I have to measure the difference between the rail pairs. This obviously requires building a differential op-amp based circuit.
The theory of the differential amplifier is pretty straight forward. It is something standard. But there is another problem. The inputs are centered at 0V. This means the output of the opamp will also go below zero. But the MCU cannot measure negative voltages. There is not even a negative voltage reference for the opamp. My idea is:

Decrease each line to 3.3V peak to peak with respect to a virtual ground
Shift each line 1.65V upwards to obtain 3 signals oscillating between 0 and 3.3V
Use the differential opamp topology for measuring the 3 signals in pairs.

I am not sure if my approach is feasable. There are open points and I am clearly missing some basics of using the opamp and power electronics. As a starting point I have built a differential amplifier with 3.3V sine waves in the inverting and non inverting inputs. I am not even sure if i can use a simple voltage divider to downscale the three phases to 3.3V level. It is also something hard to simulate because i cannot simulate the floating gnd in LTspice. So i am not sure if a simulation is useful. I do not ask any body to do my design. Any help about where to start, any suggestions or useful resources where i can get deeper information about opamp tricks would be so helpful. Probably it is not so useful but I add the pictures of my starting point as a reference.



No neutral wire? Create one.

Phase-to-neutral is called "phase voltage" and, phase-to-phase is called "line voltage".

@Antonio51 i cannot. I am redesigning an existing board. It uses OPA4330 for measuring the line voltage. I have to get benefit from 120 deg phase shift between the lines.  It makes sense. I understand what to do but i do not know how to do it.

You need theoretically only 6 resistors. Ok, 3 must sustain +/- 1 kV. Measures don't need to be bipolar. You just need only shift the last attenuated voltages towards 1.65 V.

Here is how you can do a "virtual" neutral wire.
You have just to add a "mean" voltage (1.65 V) at input "buffer" amplifiers.
Now, you can measure "unipolar" voltages (Vmax and Vmin ...).


Thank you for the answer. This clearly replies the question. The problem is my interpretation of the concept led me asking a wrong question.

I had to change my strategy due to the design restictions. I decided to use the opamp as voltage follower. I will use OPA4330. I will pair the outputs of the opamp as ab, ac and bc. The pairs will enter to the ADC pins of the MCU, which are configured as differential. Practically I will leave the differential opamp's work to the MCU. In the end I discovered that I need a voltage follower. When I simulate the opamp in differential configuration, I see that the magnitude of the sine waves is altered. I understand that this is due to the internal electronics of the opamp. It would be interesting to test this physically. Here is what I do with the opamp.
My real problem was not the input sine wave but the negative half of the wave in output of the opamap (which goes to the MCU). So I have to shift upwards the output of the opamp but not the input. How to do signal processing in the code is still an open question that I will study later.
