How to make a electronic circuit work with Delta and Star Configurations
I have developed a circuit board that measures the power consumption of a three-phase power supply with a star (wye) configuration (the circuit consumes less than 5W). My system is currently powered by a single AC phase, which is then converted to 12V DC using this Meanwell ACDC power supply (need LINE and NEUTRAL): https://www.meanwellusa.com/upload/pdf/IRM-15/IRM-15-spec.pdf.
I would like to modify my circuit board so that it can be powered by both delta or star/wye configurations. Also, I need the neutral to have a reference for my ADC in order to measure the voltage of each line.
Three phase (Delta config) -> Delta/Star transformer -> ACDC -> 12V
Three phase (Star/Wye config) -> ACDC -> 12V
After conducting extensive research, I haven't found any examples of schematics, transformers, or ICs that convert a delta configuration to a star configuration (I need a neutralc connection). Do you have any recommendations or suggestions?

What is the Delta Vac?

The AC-DC module does no need line-neutral only. It works between 2 lines until ~ 300 V AC.

Most of the time the system will be connected to a low voltage power supply (Up to 1kV). 208V for North america ~120V  phase to neutral in a wye system or 400V for Europe, ~ 230V phase to neutral in wye system.

Thank you Antonio but I need the neutral for my measurement. I am using this sensor  stpm33 from STM (https://www.st.com/en/data-converters/stpm33.html) and I need to measure the neutral.

So this is a shopping question for a PSU?  Or a measurement conversion method?

My question is: How can I transform a Delta  configuration to a Star configuration (because I need the neutral for my measure). I am looking for schematics example.

Please clarify whether the 5W power stated in the question is the power being measured, or the power consumed by the measurement device.

This is the power consumed by the measurement device.

How about an 12 V SMPS which can accept 207-400 V AC directly?

I need a neutral reference for my ADC in order to measure the voltage of each phase.

You can create a "virtual" ground with 6 resistors and measure the voltages and currents. See my answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/727993/three-phase-voltage-measurement-with-floating-gnd
